# javascript: will argument value change lead to parameter value change?

Tags: javascript

It is said in w3cschool that "If a function changes an argument's value, it does not change the parameter's original value."

However, i don't quite understand that with the following example:

```
function bar(a){
    arguments[0] = 10;
    console.log("a",a);//10
    return a;
}
function foo(cc){
    cc = 10;
    return arguments[0];
}
console.log(bar(333));//10
console.log(foo(333));//10
```

I have tested them in both chrome and firefox.
From my understanding , if argument value changes can not lead to parameter value change, why 'bar' fail to return 333?

Comment: We'd really need to see the context of that statement (though W3Schools is normally considered a poor reference site) but the thumb rule is: scalars are passed by value, objects are passes by reference. Whatever, you aren't really testing whether the original variable changes—you don't even have an original *variable*.

Comment: argument inside function does change, but original argument is not `var x = 333; bar(x); console.log(x); // 333`

Comment: Also see answers to : http://stackoverflow.com/q/518000/1531054

Comment: please read this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp  ..
JavaScript functions have a built-in object called the arguments object.
The argument object contains an array of the arguments used when the function was called (invoked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a function:

```
function bar(a) {
  arguments[0] = 10;
  return a;
}
```

Calling it like `bar(50)` will return 10, because the value *inside `bar`'s scope* was replaced by 10.

What **"If a function changes an argument's value, it does not change the parameter's original value."** means is that doing:

```
var x = 90;
var y = bar(x);

console.log(y);
console.log(x);
// y is 10
// x is still 90
```

... won't change the value of `x` *outside* of `bar`.

---

For more info see:

- [W3Schools tutorial on function parameters](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)
- [MDN's guide to functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) (in particular the section on function scope)

Answer (score 2):

As Rudolfs stated the rule is related to the variable in the outer scope. But it is not always true. For arrays & objects the rule is not applied

```js
function modify(obj) {
  obj.value = 'modified';
}

var objOuter = {value: 'original'};

console.log('The original value is ' + objOuter.value); //original
modify(objOuter);
console.log('The modified value is ' + objOuter.value); //modified
```

Comment: It is always true for primitives. For Arrays and Objects it is true only for as long as you don't modify the values they hold.